# Visualize a Blocked Task in TFS 2012 Task Board

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

Has anyone found a way to visualize when a task is blocked on the TFS 2012 task board?  It would be great if I could find a way to change the visualization (color, etc).  I saw a couple of requests on the VS board which I voted for, but was hoping someone might have found a hack =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a tfs 2012 web access plugin. Tiago Pascoal wrote a good example of one - [Team Foundation Task Board Enhancer](http://pascoal.net/2012/09/team-foundation-task-board-enhancer-version-0-3-released) - it adds a number of things (including task id) to the board.  Changing the color should be extremely easy once you can figure out if a task is blocked.

Comment: TFS 2012 update 2 will support tags (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx) meaning you can now add [Blocked] to your bug titles and have it appear as a tag off to the side